# Как прокручивать swiper на скролл окна вниз?

Tags: javascript, прокрутка, swiper, swiper.js

Коллеги, прошу указать где искать решение

САБЖ:
Есть страница, на ней есть Swiper слайдер.

ЗАДАЧА:
Надо запускать его скролл, т.е скроллить слайдер автоматом, самостоятельно, при скролле окна вниз (window.addEventListener("scroll", function (e){......})).

Я знаю, что у Swiper есть методы листания слайдов вперед-назад, но как их вызвать так, чтобы скролл был плавным?

[Песочница](https://codepen.io/emelyanova/pen/abPXzdP)

```js
const swiper = new Swiper(".swiper", {
  // Optional parameters
  slidesPerView: 4,
  spaceBetween: 30,
  // Navigation arrows
  navigation: {
    nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
    prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev"
  },
  // mousewheel: {
  //   releaseOnEdges: true,
  //   eventsTarget: "body",
  // },
});

let y = 0
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(e) {
  if (window.scrollY) {
    swiper.slideNext();
  } else {
    swiper.slidePrev()
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #ddd;
  height: 400vh;
}

section {
  margin-top: 500px;
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.swiper {
  aspect-ratio: 4/1;
  width: calc(50% + 50vw);
}

.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #fff;
  display: flex !important;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
}

.container {
  width: max(70%, 900px);
  padding: 0 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@10/swiper-bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="swiper">
      <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <!-- Slides -->
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 11</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide" style="background: red;">Slide 12</div>
      </div>
      <!-- If we need pagination -->
      <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>

      <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
      <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
      <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/10.3.1/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
```